# Error when using Auth with ORM driver kohana 3.3.0

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-auth

today i download a 3.3.0 but have error when working with Auth and ORM :

> Fatal error: Class 'Auth_Orm' not found in
>   /home/vsao4/domains/v4.mclub.vn/public_html/modules/auth/classes/Kohana/Auth.php
>   on line 37

My Auth config as below :

```
'driver'       => 'orm',
'hash_method'  => 'md5',
'hash_key'     => 'secret',
'lifetime'     => 1209600,
'session_type' => Session::$default,
'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
```

and the code is :

```
 $ars = array(
                'username'=>'manhquan',
                'password'=>'232323',
                'email'=>'manhquan@fifthmediacorp.com'
            );
            if (Auth::instance()->login($ars['username'], $ars['password']))
            {

                    // sucessfully loged
                    $this->response->body('login');

            } else {
                //TODO error
                $this->response->body('not login');
            }
```

Comment: okie i found this out. Because case sensitive in Kohana 3.3.0 we need to put in drive as  : 'driver'=>'ORM' instead of orm

Comment: Still have issue class 'ORM' not found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change

```
'driver' => 'orm',
```

to

```
'driver' => 'ORM',
```

Also, there will be an error to Database_Mysql class. Also change your config/database.php file:

```
'type' => 'mysql',
```

to

```
'type' => 'MySQL',
```

This happens due to new Kohana conventions:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions

Comment: Still have issue class 'ORM' not found.